streaming doesn't work anymore after update
hello I just updated ubuntu and video and sound doesn't work properly anymore on youtube, prime video, on chrome, brave and firefox. before update it all went well.
Help

Please Edit your question with the results of lsb_release -a  and  uname -a in a terminal, do not write it in comment.

Same Problem for me since updating. No Streaming possible. Local Videos work, but without audio (Video / Audio over HDMI).
Kernel 6.8.0-40-generic
seems to be incompatible with my HDMI Video/Audio.
WORKAROUND
I booted with my last Kernel
Linux frodo 6.5.0-45-generic #45~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jul 15 16:40:02 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
And now it works again.
update: as of a comment, I switched to a still supported kernel 5.15 (linux-image-generic)

Don't forget that the 6.5 kernel (from 23.10) is EOL & thus no longer supported, and you'll need to backport security patches yourself now. If using 22.04 as your details indicate, reverting from the HWE kernel stack to GA (or an OEM stack) would be the safer option.  (22.04 used 6.5 from 23.10 at 22.04.4, and 6.8 from 24.04 at 22.04.5 with .5 changes rolling out now).  If you're using an unsupported & unpatched kernel, keep your system offline.

Thanks, I now use 5.15 , which is still supported by ubuntu (hwe-20.04)

Why use HWE_20.04? if you're using the 22.04 kernel; the HWE 20.04 kernel was taken from linux-image-generic | 5.15.0.119.119         | jammy-security    | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x or the GA kernel stack of 22.04 ... Ubuntu docs (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) tell you how to switch from HWE or OEM to GA  (*just search for "To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:**)  Use your native kernels release (HWE kernels come from later releases)

You're right, but it's the same kernel, so nothing different. But to not confuse anyone, I edited my answer to install "linux-image-generic".
